# Automatic Conversion of JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, json, backbone.js

I was wondering if there is any way or library which allows the automatic conversion of json strings to java objects ?

i.e. similar functionality provided by Backbone for javascript.

I am fully aware you can do it step by step for each field using something like:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String body = json.get("body").toString;
```

However I have many json files to convert and manually typing out the code for ever object I need seems tedious. Is there anyway to do it autonomously ?

I.e. provide an object template which can be populated regardless of it's fields ?

Comment: Probably [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Comment: `jackson`, `moxy`, this question is offtopic

Comment: Use GSON its easy and simple to convert

Comment: Looking at GSON more carefully now. When It was initially shown to me it seemed limited but upon closer inspection it looks promising. Thanks for the recommendations

Comment: @Fido, it's a well thought out library. 
If you plan to generate JSON,   give it a `List<Map<String, String>>` and it can easily convert it.

Comment: GSON is definitely the best pick.

Answer (score 0):

Most frameworks that use ajax allow you to set a config that will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass a = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class)
```